# Is an nlobjSearchResultSet and nlobjSearch serializable during nlapiYieldScript and nlapiSetRecoveryPoint?

Tags: netsuite

I was just wondering if anybody knew if these objects are serializable for a yield or recovery.

NetSuite documentation states that the following is serializable (and thus restorable during a yield):

```
All JavaScript native types  
nlobjConfiguration  
nlobjContext  
nlobjError  
nlobjFile (files up to 5MB in size)  
nlobjRecord  
nlobjSubrecord  
nlobjSearchColumn  
nlobjSearchFilter  
nlobjSearchResult  
nlobjSearchResultCell  
all 3rd party XML Library objects
```

I just found it curious that neither was listed in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nlobjSearch certainly didn't used to be and I don't think result sets were either.

I generally ended up wrapping my search in function and returning an array of values to avoid serializable exceptions.

e.g.

```
function batchStatements(){

    var statementCusts = (function(){
        var allowResend = 'T' == nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_kotn_statement_resend');
        var filters = [
            sf('balance', null, 'greaterthanorequalto', 35),  // over the threshhold
            sf('emailtransactions', null, 'is','T'),
            sf('custentity_kotn_suppress_statements', null, 'is', 'F')
        ];
        if(!allowResend){
            var resendCutoffDays = parseInt(nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_kotn_resend_limit'),10) || 14;// 14 days allows bi-montly batches if desired. 
            var resendCutoff = new Date(new Date().getTime() - resendCutoffDays * 24 * 3600 * 1000); 
            nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "limit statements since "+ resendCutoff.toISOString());
            filters.push(sf('custentity_kotn_last_statement', null, 'notafter', nlapiDateToString(resendCutoff)));
        }
        var srch = nlapiCreateSearch('customer', 
            filters, 
            [
                sc('entityid'),
                sc('custentity_kotn_billing_email'),
                sc('email'),
                sc('subsidiary')
            ]);
        var custs = [];
        var accum = function(res){
            custs.push({
                id:res.getId(),
                billingEmail: res.getValue('custentity_kotn_billing_email'),
                email:res.getValue('email'),
                name:res.getValue('entityid'),
                subsidiary:res.getValue('subsidiary')
            });
            return true;
        }

        srch.runSearch().forEachResult(accum);
        return custs;
    })();

    var testEnt = {};

    simpleBatch(statementCusts, function(cust){
        nlapiLogExecution("AUDIT", "Sending Statement for "+ cust.name);
        var entityComms = entityPreferences.getCustEntity(cust.id);
        var pdfFile = generateStatement(cust.id);
        var emailFile = kotnMergeTemplate(entityComms.statementEmailTemplate, 'customer', cust.id);
        nlapiSendEmail(entityComms.emailFromEmp, cust.billingEmail || cust.email || entityComms.actionEmp, emailFile.getName(), emailFile.getValue(), null, null, {entity:cust.id}, pdfFile, true);
    });
}
```

simpleBatch is from https://github.com/BKnights/KotN-Netsuite
it handles governance management by tracking the max governance of the function and yielding when needed.